# How create bundle with esbuild with import modules

Tags: javascript, bundler, esbuild

i have this module

```
import * as cborg from 'cborg'
import { CID } from 'multiformats/cid'
function cidEncoder (obj) {

}
....
```

when i build module with this command line

```
"bundle": "./node_modules/.bin/esbuild  ./dist/index.mjs  --bundle   --outfile=./dist/out.mjs",
```

I have bundle without export default

when i build module with this command line

```
"build": "./node_modules/.bin/esbuild  ./src/index.js  --target=es2020   --outfile=./dist/index.mjs",
```

This import not include in module

```
import * as cborg from 'cborg'
import { CID } from 'multiformats/cid'
```

How can i create module with include all modules in one file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you haven't specified a `platform`, so the default will be *browser*, and according to the [esbuild docs](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#platform) the output `format` (which you also haven't specified) will default to *iife*:

> When the platform is set to browser (the default value):
>
> - When bundling is enabled the default output format is set to iife, which wraps the generated JavaScript code in an immediately-invoked function expression to prevent variables from leaking into the global scope.

So given that you're trying to generate an ESM module (i.e. based on the `*.mjs` extension on the build output file) you'll need an *esm* output format, which is the default when specifying a *neutral* `platform`:

```
"bundle": "esbuild  ./src/index.js  --bundle --platform=neutral  --outfile=./dist/out.mjs",
```

You'll also need to add a default export to your `index.js` file:

```
import * as cborg from 'cborg'
import { CID } from 'multiformats/cid'

export default function cidEncoder (obj) {
  ...
}
```

Hope that helps.